# Jersey erro with JSON in Tomcat7

Tags: json, jersey, tomcat7

I deployed a rest using Grizzly container and have used the code below to send a JSON object. Everything works very well.

```
ClientResponse response = wr.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, cliente);
String body = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("status="+response.getStatus() + "\n" + body);
```

When I deployed the same rest example in Tomcat 7, this code stopped working showing the following message:

**org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<crud.Cliente>]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)**

I really dont know why....it works on Grizzly embebed container and not work in tomcat?
Anyone know What's going on?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `Grizzly` uses it's own serializer/deserializer. Try to add an empty constructor to `Cliente` class:

`public Cliente() {
};`

Comment: I've done this constructor before posting the question! Works in Grizzly but not in tomcat ...